# MYSQL master-slave fail if slave behind proxy?

Tags: mysql, proxy, replication

I have two linux machines, A and B. A is master and B is slave. Besides, B is behind proxy. In B , I have set http_proxy and socks_proxy env variable.

However, B cannot connect to A and report `ERROR CODE 2013`

```
error connecting to master 'repl@137.189.145.40:3306' 
Slave_IO_Running  No 
Slave_SQL_Running Yes
```

I try to fix it in whole days but still in vain. Whats' wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must grant privileges to `repl` user to allow connect from the proxy P, something like this:

```
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'P' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pa$$w0rd';
```

Comment: I have done it already

Comment: Did you run `flush privileges;`? Can you `telnet master_IP 3306` from slave?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think mysql supports http proxys unless youre talking about the Tool "MYSQL Proxy".

You might need a simple port forward or vpn for this connection.

Would be awesome if they added http proxy support in the newer version or did i just miss the part in the manual...